# Updating database with values in properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

I have a property file(**.properties**) which is having some values that needs to be updated in the database.

I can specify key with **delimiter '#'** like

```
table_name#column_name#where_clause_column#where_value = value_to_be_updated
```

Above will generate an update like(logic to generate update statement is written in Java by me)

```
update table_name set column_name = value_to_be_updated where where_clause_column = where_value
```

It is working fine. I want to know if this actually is the right way to go about it or is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: How complex can the update queries be? So simple queries like the one sighted, string operations should be fine.

Comment: @Hirak - Queries will be simple like above.

Comment: show java code what you have written to build update statement?

Comment: this approach works but accordingly properties should always be a clean combo of key value pairs. but the key you have created with multiple value delimiters. i think your code will look cluttered when you access the key from a java code. why not make a separte entry for your delimiter keys in another file and call it from there. by this your code will be clean and readable but you can live with the overhead of another property file in your code

Comment: @vikeng21- Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Approach looks good Anand..It would be better to use batch update for performance point of view.

```
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "value"); //will be called multiple times (as per your query parameters)
    preparedStatement.addBatch(); //will be called multiple times (one per query)
    preparedStatement.executeBatch(); //will be called only once (one per batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't break anything but unless you have an imperious reason to do so, I think you are misusing property files. According to the jdk Properties is a subclass of HashTable, and you don't use it as a hash or a dictionary but more as a sequential file. I think the delimiter and the file name (or path) could go in a properties file, because they are configuration elements. But the data itself should go in a simple text file that you can read and process one line at a time, with no need for loading the entire file in memory. And thanks to buffering you won't lose anything in performances.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using too much convention!
- Sql query is not a key/value pair.
  Properties are configuration values managed as key/value pairs.
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

A better approach:
Maintain a .sql file, where you could run it at start.
Writing directly the query will be more clear.